# How To Manually Rollback A Migration in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, prisma

Looks like my ORM, [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/), does [not allow for rolling back a migration](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4617#discussioncomment-215868). How have folks using Prisma rolled back a migration? Is there a way to manually rollback a migration with MySQL commands?

Comment: You can manually make an ALTER TABLE to reverse most types of schema changes, but some types of changes naturally lose data. For example, if your migrations was a DROP COLUMN, you could add the column back to the table manually, but that won't reconstruct the data values that used to be in that column.

Comment: PlanetScale has a fancy feature to recover an original table — with its data — after an improper migration (see blog: https://planetscale.com/blog/its-fine-rewind-revert-a-migration-without-losing-data), but this is not simply a MySQL solution; it requires that you manage your MySQL cluster with their Vitess platform.

Answer (score 2):

Prisma has added two commands since version `3.9.0` which allows you to rollback your migration.

Combining `npx prisma migrate diff` and `npx prisma db execute` would allow you to rollback.

Here's the reference to official documentation which goes through the workflow: [Moving backwards and reverting all changes](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/production-troubleshooting#moving-backwards-and-reverting-all-changes).

Please note the commands are still in preview so you would need to add `--preview-feature` flag while executing the commands.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can run the command:

```bash
npx prism migrate resolve --rolled-back some_change_description --force
```

so it will resolve the inconsistencies in the table and run the migration again, you can also downgrade migrate and then run the deployment again.

Comment: Get `! unknown or unexpected option: --force` is this a new feature? Using Prisma 4.8.1. Without the force flag it says `Cannot be rolled back bacause it is not in a failed state.`